# Starting index of Riemann sums

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

Let M be some positive integer. Does the following converge?$$\lim_{d\to+\infty}\sum_{k=M}^{d}f(\frac{k}{d})\frac{1}{d} $$
$f$ here is well defined, for example bounded by positive C and measurable on $[0,1]$.

I think it converges since $\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}f(\frac{k}{d})\frac{1}{d}\leq \frac{CM}{d}\to 0$ so:
\begin{align*}\lim_{d\to+\infty}\sum_{k=M}^{d}f(\frac{k}{d})\frac{1}{d} &=\lim_{d\to+\infty}\sum_{k=M}^{d}f(\frac{k}{d})\frac{1}{d}+\lim_{d\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}f(\frac{k}{d})\frac{1}{d}\\&=\lim_{d\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{d}f(\frac{k}{d})\frac{1}{d}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx<\infty
\end{align*}
Would appreciate if someone can point out any mistake.

Comment: Your argument works fine  for any Riemann integrable function $f$.

Comment: Please change all the $i$'s to $k$'s or all the $k$'s to $i$'s.

Comment: @uniquesolution thank for pointing it out.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you. I wasn't sure since something this basic should have shown up somewhere in one of my textbooks but I couldn't remember seeing sth similar.

Comment: To use "measurable" is certainly not a good idea when the whole limit process involves only countably many function values. For example $f(x)=\mathbb 1_{\Bbb Q}(x)$ is measurable and bounded and yet the sum does not converge to the integral (though in this particular case, it at least still converges).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen would riemann integrability work here?